# Natural ways to define addition on the edge set of the hypercube $Q_n$

Tags: combinatorics, definition, arithmetic

The hypercube of dimension $n$ is defined as the graph $Q_n$, where $V(Q_n)= \{0,1\}^n $ and $E(Q_n)= \{ \{x,y\}  : x,y \in \{0,1\}^n \text{ and } |x_i-y_i|=0 \text{ for all except one } i \in [n]\}$ (i.e. two vertices are connected by an edge iff they differ in one bit).

As the title suggests, I am looking for useful ways to define addition on the set $E(Q_n)$.

Please don't hesitate to perhaps make multiple suggestions, but make sure to motivate them (i.e. why would you define it that way?).

\

Just for the record:

A possible answer would be to identify $E(Q_n)$ as $\mathbb{F}_n \times \mathbb{F}_2^{n-1}$ via $ \Phi : E(Q_n) \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_n \times \mathbb{F}_2^{n-1}$, where $\Phi( \{x,y\}) := (i, x_i)$
with the $i$ such that $|x-y| = e_i$ is the $i$-th unit vector in $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ (i.e. this is the direction of $\{x,y\}$)  and
$(x_i)_j := x_j $  $\forall j < i$,
$(x_i)_j := x_{j+1}$  $\forall j \geq i$  (i.e. $x_i$ contains all, except the $i$-th coordinate of $x$).

However this group structure is most likely not what I am looking for. I want to apply Bogolyubov's Lemma (about additive subsets of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$) onto $E(Q_n)$, but using the structure $\Phi$ provides, it seems as if this doesn't work very well.

Can someone find another natural group structure on $E(Q_n)$?